# How to avoid setting inline onClickListner in getView()

Tags: android, listview, onclick, listener

I have got ListView with a custom Adapter. Every row contains clickable buttons and texts.

At the moment onClickListeners are set in the body of `getView()`, this is quite insane idea because this method is called very frequently. Inside every onClick function, I need access to the private data to call new activity with the bundle.

How can I move the onClick definition outside getView() routine?

When onClick will be called I need info about the position of the list element (to access private data) and which View was clicked (to start the correct Activity).

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertview == null) {
        convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.photo_tweet_row, null);
    }

    TextView userTweet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.feed_user_tweet_body);
    RepliesButton repliesBtn = (RepliesButton) v.findViewById(R.id.feed_replies_button);

    Status twitterDataItem = getItem(position);

    if (twitterDataItem != null) {

        if (userTweet != null) {
            userTweet.setText(twitterDataItem.getText());
        }
        if (repliesBtn != null) {
            repliesBtn.setText(" replies");
        }
        
        userTweet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                    
              Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ProfileActivity.class); 
              intent.putExtra(getContext().getString(R.string.serializable_user), twitterDataItem.getUser());
              getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        
        repliesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!twitterDataItem.getComments().contentEquals("0")) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getContext(), RepliesToFeedActivity.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("photoTweet", twitterDataItem);
                    getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: where is the getContext()? i working on similar listview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your activitiy has to implement the OnClickListener, and move the implemented method up to the activity level.

Based on the `view` parameter of the method you are able to detect from which UI object the event came from (button, textview).

As for how to detect for which record/row in a listview. You have to set a custom `tag` on the  buttons and textviews in the `getView` method, that you will read in the event via `getTag` this tag can be a custom object too if string is not enough. Probably/recommended way is to be the position in the adapter.

Comment: That is what I thought. Unfortunately I'm using `setTag` for slow adapter. I will rebuild my code and try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that Pentium10 answer is not correct. If the checkbox is to be clickable and checkable independently from the list item itself, (say it is defined in the list item xml layout), then it will intercept the click event, and the list item  (the list's OnItemClickListener) will not receive the click at all.
Therefore you must implement the onClickListener in the adapter itself - either in getView(), or have the adapter implement onClickListener - in this case the items must be tagged for the listener to know which item it is operating on.

Comment: Yes, you have to set onClickListener on every view (inside row layout) from which you would like to receive callbacks.