# Starting an AsyncTask out of an ListAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, onclicklistener

I've got an Problem, to start a new AsyncTask out of an ListAdapter. But frist of all, here is the situation:

I've an Activity, contains an Listview. This ListView is filled via Adapter

```
ReservationAdapter adapter = new ReservationAdapter(self, (List<Reservation>) msg.obj);
reservationListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The ReservationAdapter have custom list items (2 Strings + 1 cancle Button). Below the getView()-Method:

```
    @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_reservation, null);
    }

    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.removeButton);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView subTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subTitle);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Here I need to start the AsyncTask
        }
    });

    // Here I'm filling the Labels... (not important)

    return view;
}
```

I know, how to start the Task out of an listener in an normal activity, but how do I start it from the onClicklistener in the Adapter class?

Comment: I dont get the question? You can start the async task anywhere you want basically. What is actually bothering you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I do not agree with this design choice.  Starting async task from you adapter is normally not a good idea.  However you would start it just like you would from an activity or fragment.

If you have a class that extends async task that you want to start for example:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    public MyTask(){}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
       return null
    }

}
```

In your `onClick` you can simply start this task like this:

```
MyTask task = new MyTask();
task.execute();
```

Another way would be to define the the task as another inner class inside your onClick (also bad design) and execute it from there.  Something like this:

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
                    {
                        return null;  
                    }
                }.execute();
            }
```

I highly recommend that you move your task to the activity/fragment if possible.  [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is the documentation for async task.  Go through it to get a better understanding of when and how to use it.

Comment: mhm, thanks I think it's better to do it in my activity. But how can I call a method in the Activity from inside the listener?

Comment: Based on you current implementation there isn't a good way calling a method in activity. Have look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438408/how-to-avoid-setting-inline-onclicklistner-in-getview) question.  Also have a look at [onItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html).  This will make the whole row clickable instead of the button but you can implement it on activity side.

Comment: Yeah I've done it as you said and know it works fine :) there was also an stupid error of mine.